# Access Denied [Failure - Status Code 403]

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I'm trying to do a query - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user.name@contoso.com/messages?$select=from,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients on GRAPH Explorer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#.

But I'm getting an Access Denied error - Failure - Status Code 403, 522ms Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions.

I've already checked all the available permissions from Microsoft Graph Explorer.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user.name@contoso.com/messages?$select=from,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients

Failure - Status Code 403, 522ms Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions.

{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "83a65052-d66c-4b26-a272-dd99cb84be76",
            "date": "2019-06-24T18:02:45"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Though GraphExplorer you either have to use the `me` reference and work with your own account or you have to go through the process of generating a valid token, adding to the headers, etc. and then using it.  Personally I'd rather look at the docs and work via `postman`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try removing the `mail.readbasic` scope? I think that's only meant to be used when calling the beta API version (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/etc). Since you've already granted the application this permission you could just call the beta version instead of v1.0 for testing purposes.  That should work if you're just trying out the APIs in the explorer and not building a production application quite yet.

Comment: Are you referring to Mail.Read permission?